# Adobe Captivate 8 - sending the .CPTX file to another Captivate 8 user

Tags: adobe-captivate

I feel a little silly asking this, but I have looked everywhere. I am going to be submitting (via moodle) my .CPTX file which contains FLV video in it. I will be submitting it unpublished. Do I need to include the copies of the FLV files that are on my computer with this submission for the receiver to play/publish my .CPTX on her computer (instructor wants to grade file set up as well as everything else). I am using the Progressive Download Video option (choose if the video is hosted on any internal server, web server, or Adobe Media Server) because the FLV videos are just on my computer. I asked her and she said "test it on another computer" - I don't have another computer :( Has anyone had any experience with this? 
(superuser.com didnt have the captivate tags - said i needed some 300 reputation)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide the FLV files as well. The only other way would be if you upload the FLV files to your LMS (or a web server) and then provide your colleague URLs for them. In Captivate you can then just stream the videos from the server.